# Fetch second row only from Mongodb and display using Jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I am fetching data from mongodb using nodejs using `findAll()` method. Now in jade templating engine I would like to show data(which are basically some quiz questions) one by one i.e. only first record(i.e. first quiz question from collection) will show initially and then when the 'NEXT' button will be clicked then the next record from collection i.e. second quiz question will be shown and so on.

Now I am able to fetch and show first quiz question but when I am clicking the "NEXT" button I am getting an error on chrome's developer console which is saying `"Uncaught ReferenceError: myquiz is not defined"`. Now `myquiz` is a part(collection in Mongodb) of my server.js.How do I fetch the second record from `myquiz` in Jade and that too when user clicks "NEXT" button. As I am successful in fetching the first record but after that it does not work.

The JADE code is given below:

```
doctype html

html(lang="en")

  head
    script(src="/javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")

    h1= title
  body
  div#myquestions
    ul
      li #{myquiz[0].Question}
      li #{myquiz[0].Option1}
      li #{myquiz[0].Option2}
      li #{myquiz[0].Option3}
      li #{myquiz[0].Option4}
      button(class="Button" id="NextButton") Next

    script(type="text/javascript"). 
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#NextButton").click(function() {
         $("#myquestions").html(myquiz[1].Question,myquiz[1].Option1,myquiz[1].Option2,myquiz[1].Option3,myquiz[1].Option4);
         });
       });
```

The relevant code from quizprovider.js is given below:

```
....
....
QuizProvider.prototype.getCollection = function(callback) {
  this.db.collection('myquiz', function(error, quiz_collection) {
    if( error ) callback(error);
    else callback(null, quiz_collection);
  });
};

QuizProvider.prototype.findAll = function(callback) {
    this.getCollection(function(error, quiz_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        quiz_collection.find().toArray(function(error, results) {
          if( error ) callback(error)
          else callback(null, results)
        });
      }
    });
};
```

The relevant code from app.js file is given below:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , QuizProvider = require('./quizprovider').QuizProvider;

var app = express();

      app.use(express.logger('dev'));
      app.use(express.bodyParser());
      app.use(express.methodOverride());
      app.use(app.router);
      app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
      app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    });

    app.configure('development', function(){
      app.use(express.errorHandler());
    });

    var qProvider= new QuizProvider('localhost', 27017);
    .....
    .....

        app.get('/', function(req, res){
          qProvider.findAll(function(error, ques){
              res.render('index', {
                    title: 'Questions',
                    myquiz:JSON.stringify(ques)
                });                            
          });
        });
```

Now how can I fetch and display the second record from the collection i.e. second quiz question when user click "NEXT" button.Am I doing it the right way or is there any other way to achieve this.Please help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I finally managed to find a solution to this problem.First I performed `JSON.stringify` operation on `ques` and then retrieved the records into a Javascript array `data` using `push` operation and then displayed the array elements(i.e. `data` elements) using Jquery.

```
$( "#myquestions" ).html(data[0]);
$( "#option1" ).html(data[1]);
$( "#option2" ).html(data[2]);
$( "#option3" ).html(data[3]);
$( "#option4" ).html(data[4]);
```

Now to fetch and display the second record from the array(on "NEXT" button click) I used a counter.The initial value of counter is stored in a textbox(which is hidden) and then the counter in incremented inorder to fetch records one by one from the array and then these are displayed using Jquery `.html()` method. The code is given below:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    script(src="/javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")
    h1= title
  body   
   div#myquestions
   div#option1
   div#option2
   div#option3
   div#option4
   div#myNextbutton   
      button(class="Button" id="NextButton") Next
   div#mytextbox
      input(type="hidden" name="TextBox" id="TextBox" value="4")    

    script(type="text/javascript"). 
     $(function() {
         var availablTags = !{myquiz};
         var data = [];
         for(var i=0;i<availablTags.length;i++){
         data.push(availablTags[i]['Question']),
         data.push(availablTags[i]['Option1']),
         data.push(availablTags[i]['Option2']),
         data.push(availablTags[i]['Option3']),
         data.push(availablTags[i]['Option4'])
          }
         console.log(data);

         $( "#myquestions" ).html(data[0]);
         $( "#option1" ).html(data[1]);
         $( "#option2" ).html(data[2]);
         $( "#option3" ).html(data[3]);
         $( "#option4" ).html(data[4]);
         $("#NextButton").click(function(){
             var counter = $('#TextBox').val();
             counter++ ;
             $( "#myquestions" ).html(data[counter++]);
             $( "#option1" ).html(data[counter++]);
             $( "#option2" ).html(data[counter++]);
             $( "#option3" ).html(data[counter++]);
             $( "#option4" ).html(data[counter]);
             $('#TextBox').val(counter);
                });
         });
```

This is one logic I could think of and it works.But if you guys have any better suggestion please let me know.Hope the solution helps someone else too who is facing same kind of problem.